# C- Code won't be executed, can someone help me?

Tags: c, if-statement

Ok, so I'm a computer science student (so I'm still learning) and I'm trying to program a drink maschine thingy. The thing is, it only executes the first if- block. I can't find my mistake and would really appreciate some help, so that I can fix the mistake and know what I did wrong.

I made some comments in the code, so it's better understandable for non German speakers, since the main text (which is mostly unimportant) is in german.

Here is the complete code for reverence

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void Fkt(int);

int main(void) {
    int x;   /*Not important in this part of code */
 
    char G;  /*The drink you choose will be G*/
    float p; /* p = price */
    
       
       printf("*** Getraenke Automat *** \n*W) Wasser    (0.5 Euro)* \n*B) Bionade     (1 Euro)*\n*O) Orangensaft (2 Euro)*\n***********************\n\nBitte ein Getränk auswaeheln ");  /*Basically just asking what drink you want with the prices */
    scanf("%c", &G);  /* User picks drink*/
       
    if ( G == 119 || 87) {    /*This if block works perfectly fine */
        printf("\n Bitte Zahlen Sie 0.5 Euro ");
        scanf("%f", &p);
        if ( p == 0.5) { /*If you pay the right amount of money */
            printf("\n Entnehmen Sie Ihr Getränk \n");
            }
        else { /*For the wrong amount of money*/
            printf("\nGeben Sie den richtigen Betrag ein!\n");
        }
    }
    
   else if ( G == 66 || 98) {  /* This one is stated as "Will never be executed */
        printf("\n Bitte Zahlen Sie 1 Euro ");
        scanf("%f", &p);
        if ( p == 1) {
            printf("\n Entnehmen Sie Ihr Getränk \n");
            }
        else {
            printf("\nGeben Sie den richtigen Betrag ein!\n");
        }
    }
    
        
    return 0;
}

void Fkt(int x){
    printf("\n------------\n");
    
}
```

I tried to give every drink a different pice (Lemonade 1 Euro, Water 0.5 Cent) but no matter what input is given it always only gives me the price of the first drink.
I don't know if I made a small silly error or just did it completly wrong.

So here is my problem area:

```
 if ( G == 119 || 87) {    /*This if block works perfectly fine */
        printf("\n Bitte Zahlen Sie 0.5 Euro ");
        scanf("%f", &p);
        if ( p == 0.5) { /*If you pay the right amount of money */
            printf("\n Entnehmen Sie Ihr Getränk \n");
            }
        else { /*For the wrong amount of money*/
            printf("\nGeben Sie den richtigen Betrag ein!\n");
        }
    }
    
   else if ( G == 66 || 98) {  /* This one is stated as "Will never be executed */
        printf("\n Bitte Zahlen Sie 1 Euro ");
        scanf("%f", &p);
        if ( p == 1) {
            printf("\n Entnehmen Sie Ihr Getränk \n");
            }
        else {
            printf("\nGeben Sie den richtigen Betrag ein!\n");
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. In this code `G == 119 || 87` a) You should not use magic numbers. Use character constants like `'W'` etc. b) That expression does not do what you expect. You want `G=='w' || G=='W'`

Comment: And use `double` instead of `float`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want statements like `if ( G == 66 || G == 98)` instead of what you have.  I don't think the code as written does what you think it does.

When you do `G == 66 || 98` it will first evaluate `G == 66` (which will evaluate to `true` or `false`) and then apply that value to 98 via the `||` operator, which will always return `true` (`||` is usually applied to boolean values). It will not check whether G is 66 or 98...

Comment: Exactly what do you expect `G == 119 || 87` to do? Guessing syntax is not a good way to learn. Hint: It is the same as `G == (119 || 87)`

Comment: Not so, @klutt.  The `==` operator has higher precedence than does `||`, so `G == 119 || 87` is equivalent to `(G == 119) || 87`.  And since `87` is truthy and the expression has no side effects, that's also equivalent to just `1`.

Comment: @klutt `==` has a higher operator precedence than `||`. So `(G == 119) || 87` is what you get... https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Alright, thanks guys. I see my mistake now. Thank you!

Comment: In C, any number apart from 0 is true, so 87 is true.

Comment: @Ron Haha, you're correct. And I posted the comment in the wrong place. It was intended to go to the question and not the answer. My main point is that it does not do what OP think it does. :)

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yep, that's correct. My bad. See above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is because you are saying

`if ( G == 119 || 87)`

Here, it tests if G is equal to 119, and if 87 is not 0.

The following code might help you understand how C works when using int as bool.

```
int a = 5;
if (a)
{
    printf("Not zero\n");
} else {
    printf("Zero\n");
}
a = 0;
if (a)
{
    printf("Not zero\n");
} else {
    printf("Zero\n");
}
```

The code above will print

```
Not zero
Zero
```

You should probably try

```
 if ( G == 119 || G == 87) {    /*This if block works perfectly fine */
        printf("\n Bitte Zahlen Sie 0.5 Euro ");
        scanf("%f", &p);
        if ( p == 0.5) { /*If you pay the right amount of money */
            printf("\n Entnehmen Sie Ihr Getränk \n");
            }
        else { /*For the wrong amount of money*/
            printf("\nGeben Sie den richtigen Betrag ein!\n");
        }
    }
    
   else if ( G == 66 || G == 98) {  /* This one is stated as "Will never be executed */
        printf("\n Bitte Zahlen Sie 1 Euro ");
        scanf("%f", &p);
        if ( p == 1) {
            printf("\n Entnehmen Sie Ihr Getränk \n");
            }
        else {
            printf("\nGeben Sie den richtigen Betrag ein!\n");
        }
```

Comment: *`and if 87 is not null`* null has a specific meaning in C. You should say is not zero.